# Setting Custom Field Name and Code

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, bean-validation, spring-validator

I am trying to use Bean Validation for validation in my Spring App. I have the below field defined in my bean -

```
@NotNull(message = "CUSTOMERROR-1000")
private String firstName;
```

Here I have defined CUSTOMERROR-1000 as "Field is mandatory" in my property file. In my ControllerAdvice class , i am able to retrieve the details using the code below :

```
getBindingResult().getFieldError().getField()
getBindingResult().getFieldError().getCode()
getBindingResult().getFieldError().getDefaultMessage()
```

Here I get the field name as firstName. Is there a way to annotate the field and set the value as "First Name"? Similarly is there a way to set the code value via annotation?

Comment: I annotated the field (firstName) in the bean in order to make use of JSR-303 validation. Using this line "getBindingResult().getFieldError().getField()" , I am able to get the name of the field which is firstName. I am able to get the default message using this line "getBindingResult().getFieldError().getDefaultMessage()".  However is there a way to pass customer errorCode similar to default message is passed. Eg: @NotNull(code= "ERR-CUST-01").I also want to pass "First Name" instead of getting the field name "firstName". Eg: @NotNull(label= "First Name").

Comment: I wanted to check if the custom field name and error code value can be set using some annotation and retrieved while returning the error back to consumer.

Comment: Are you looking specifically for an annotation-only approach?

Comment: Yes , I am prefer annotation. Any other standard approach will help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to create your own constraints. Than you can add additional properties, label, errorCode etc., set values to them and use them. See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-compound

Than you can define your error message like this:
`Error code: {errorCode} - {label} is mandatory`

Comment: A custom constraint would be able to handle any necessary custom validation properties you want. Additionally, based on the mention of their property file, they may want to look into [Validation Message Interpolation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html) for custom message construction.

Comment: Well, thats definitely my choice, i guess he uses same prop. for multiple fields and want a way to customise it, like adding filed names etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach (IMO) still seems like a lot of work for a trivial (IMO) benefit. The outcome of the `getFieldError` is furnished by a [`Validator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html). Knowing that, you can supply a custom validator to your `DataBinder`. Your validator can look like this:

1. First define your custom validator

   ```
   public class FirstNameValidator implements Validator{

        public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
            return YourClass.class.equals(clazz);
        }

        public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
            if(obj != null){
               YourClass theObj = (YourClass)obj;
                  if(theObj.getFirstName() == null || theObj.getFirstName().trim()==""){
                     e.rejectValue("First Name","CUSTOMERROR-1000");
                  }
         }

      }
   ```

   }
2. After which you now register your custom validator with the context's databinder (I'm assuming you're running Spring MVC here):

   ```
   @InitBinder
   protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       binder.addValidators(new FirstNameValidator());
   }
   ```

This will ensure you get the name in the format you want. Again, it's a lot of typing (the annotation-based approach is just as long, with even more typing to support the annotation) for a bit of fancy text.